# QDialog is on top of every Application

Tags: qt, qmainwindow, qdialog, qwebengineview

we need to execute dialog on top of every windows application.

we tried some code below for that but its not working for us.

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
setModal(true);
setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
```

can you Please let us know how can we achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to make it appear on top or be modal for all windows?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34620247/make-qdialog-modal-to-operating-system

Answer (score 0):

It should work with only:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

Then remove:

```
setModal(true);
setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
```

And try again.